# Wrong position of redirect on large screens

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

When I'm on a screen with 1920px or less, my anchor link will redirect the page to the normal location.
But, if I am with a screen of 3000px, when I try to do the same action, the browser will go to the top of page, not redirecting where the Id is.

Sorry if I can't be more accurate on the bug, it is because I can't really code anything like that.
I'm using Angular, but I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with the problem.

Any of you guys can think of an solution to it? Not sure if only css can solve this. Pretty sure I'll need a JS.

I can't really reproduce this bug on codepen or so, but I can give a link for you guys to test it out.
Go to
https://www.4rsistemas.com.br/
1º To see the normal link redirect, use a window of 1920px or less and click in the "Produtos" link on the menu, and then click on the "Modulos" link on the menu.

It will redirect like it should, to the "Modulos" Section.

Now, do the same with a screen of 3000px or more, you will see the problem.

Comment: I think the problem is that the page is jumping to the location of an anchor before the content is loaded. And then it(the anchor) is being moved to a different place after the content appears and everything pops into the right place and scales properly. I don't really know how to solve it though.

Comment: Anchors + Dynamic content = wrong position.